# DBPedia as Table not having all the properties

Tags: dataset

I browsed a sample for available data at http://dbpedia.org/page/Sachin_Tendulkar. I wanted these properties as columns, so I downloaded the CSV files from http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaAsTables.

Now, when I browse the data for the same entity "Sachin_Tendulkar", I find that many of the properties are not available. e.g. the property "dbpprop:bestBowling" is not present.

How can I get all the properties that I can browse through the direct resource page.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but the first four lines of Athlete.csv list the fields for that CSV file. So it seems they only pull specific fields for athletes, and the extra fields are ignored. This isn't mentioned explicitly on the page you note, but they do say "we provide *some* of the core DBpedia" (emphasis added). I assumed they meant specific records, but apparently it also means only specific fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was already answered on the DBpedia-discussion mailing list, by Daniel:

> Hi Abhay,
>
> the DBpediaAsTables dataset only contains the properties in the
> dbpedia-owl namespace (mapping-based infobox data) and not those from
> the dbpprop (raw infobox properties) namespace (regarding the
> differences see [1]).
>
> However, as you are only interested in the data about specific
> entities, take a look at the CSV link at the bottom of the entity's
> description page, e.g., for your example this link is [2].
>
> Cheers,
> Daniel
>
> [1] wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets#h434-10
>
> [2] dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=DESCRIBE+%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Sachin_Tendulkar%3E&format=text%2Fcsv

On the [DBpediaAsTables web page](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaAsTables), you can find out which datasets were used to generate the tables: instance_types_en, labels, short_abstracts_en, mappingbased_properties_en, geo_coordinates_en.
Also, I want to clarify that DBpediaAsTables contains all instances from DBpedia 2014, and with "we provide some of the core DBpedia data" we want to say that not all datasets are included in the tables (but only the 5 I stated before)

If you want to generate your own tables that will contain custom properties, please refer to the section [Generate your own Custom Tables](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaAsTables#h347-4).

Cheers,

Petar

Comment: Yeah, I had put that question on that thread - But I did not receive this mail??

Answer (score 0):

The official answer:

```
Date: Sun, 23 Nov 2014 03:08:19 +0100
From: Petar Ristoski <petar.ristoski@informatik.uni-mannheim.de>
To: 'Barry Carter' <carter.barry@gmail.com>
Subject: RE: CSV tables don't have all properties?

Hi Carter,

The question was already answered on the DBpedia mailing list, but I will
try to clarify it again. On the DBpedia as Tables web page says that "For
each class in the DBpedia ontology (such as Person, Radio Station, Ice
Hockey Player, or Band) we provide a single CSV/JSON file which contains all
instances of this class. Each instance is described by its URI, an English
label and a short abstract, the MAPPING-BASED INFOBOX data describing the
instance (extracted from the English edition of Wikipedia), geo-coordinates,
and external links." As you can see we only provide the mapping-based
infobox properties (dbpedia-owl namespace), while the properties from the
dbpprop (raw infobox properties) namespace are completely ignored.
Therefore, dbpprop:bestBowling is missing from the file.

Also, there is a section "Generating your own Custom Tables" [1], where we
explain how to generate your own tables that will contain the properties you
need.

Regards,

Petar

[1] http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaAsTables#h347-4
```